# Pygame lags on simple game

Tags: python, pygame, lag

I am trying to build a game in pygame, however any movement feels laggy. Its not a big lag but more like a small stuttering.

I created a boiled down version to showcase this.
The code in the git below does nothing but create a red ball that moves over your display.
Despite its simplicity, the lag still remains.

https://github.com/Ogorf/Spong

Thanks in advance to anyone taking the time!

EDIT: I run the main with:

```
$ python -m Spong.main
```

from the Spong folder

Comment: Does this answer the question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61012560

Comment: @Gantendo sadly not, the draw function already is in the application loop rather than the event loop

Comment: Have you been able to measure the frame time and see if it's irregular?

Comment: This code doesn't run.  I began fixing errors but gave up on the pygame.draw.color() error.  What version of Python and Pygame are you using?

Comment: @Vaillancourt I printed `dt` (defined Spong.game_loop) and it would give me 16 or 17 as a value, one single spike at 23, so overall pretty regular i think

Comment: I should have worded that a little more nicely by saying that "I can't get this code to run."  Sorry for my lack of manners.

Comment: @IanMoote You are correct in that i should ve added some intructions (added them now in the main post). I use python3.10.0. I appreciate you took the time and tried to run it.
With the command as in the first post, the code runs fine on my end (besides the lag :D )

Comment: Instead of calling `clock.tick(fps)`, try calling `clock.tick_busy_loop(fps)`.

Comment: @Ogorf This is a very good question.  I've been working on this on-and-off all afternoon.  I'm not a PyGame guru, but solutions which should have smoothed out that jerkiness have not.

Comment: @Ogorf I'll be spending a lot more time investigating this today because I find this problem both intriguing and challenging.  As I said, the code I wrote independently moved the ball smoothly across the screen so it will be interesting to discover what it is in your code that is causing this problem.  My answer got voted down as poor quality so I will not be replying further to this question, but I will be watching to see what insights others can provide on it.  I hope you get a quality answer soon.

Comment: Sounds like a vsync issue. Have you tried `pygame.display.set_mode(...,vsync=1)`?

Comment: I tried your code. I see jitter. I also printed the result of `pygame.draw.circle`, and glanced over the results; as it's been mentioned, it works in integers, and since you supply float values, the fraction part will likely be chopped off or rounded during the rendering. That being said, over the course of the test, the distance is consistent with the speed set. Aside from the suggestion I made previously, you could also pass in `1000.0/self.fps` to `self.tick` instead of `dt` to have a more consistent update.

Comment: @Mangata i made it work using your solution. I had to set the pygame.SCALED flag in display.set_mode aswell, but then all the jittering disappeared! If you make a post and add this to your answer, i ll mark it as correct answer. Thanks to you and all others :)